# Pass .each loop reference object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreach

I am writing a code in ruby on rails where I am creating dynamic rows in table which involves a `.each` loop. I want to pass the `.each` loop reference object but it gives me an error.

Following is the code:

```
<% pworkflows.workflow_executions_list.each do |wf| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= wf.execution_status %></td>
    <td>
      <% if(wf.start_timestamp != nil) %>
        <%= wf.start_timestamp.localtime; %> UTC
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= wf.close_status %></td>
    <td><%= wf.execution.run_id %></td>
    <td><%= button_to "Details",{ :controller => "pages", :action => "mainpage",:rulesetinstance=>rInsId, :ndetails=>wf} %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

`:ndetails=>wf` gives an error. wf is not being recognized as a correct syntax to send.
Please suggest a way.

the error being:

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<ComRuleManagement::WorkflowExecutionObject:0x00003da1751528>
```

Comment: what is the error. can you share. also please confirm pworkflows is an array or object.

Comment: What is the value of `pworkflows.workflow_executions_list`?

Comment: yes, pworkflows is an object that had workflow executions list which is an array of objects.

Comment: Which line is that error referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
<%= button_to "Details",{ :controller => "pages", :action => "mainpage",:rulesetinstance=>rInsId, :ndetails=>wf} %>
```

you are building an html tag.  (since `button_to` is an html helper). The extra options you pass through, in this instance ":rulesetinstance" and ":ndetails" will be used to make extra attributes in the element, like `rulesetinstance="123"`.  However, if you pass the wf object through, then rails will call to_s on it, and you'll end up with something that looks like this `ndetails="#<Wf:0x7f518dfc6e68>"`.  This is almost certainly not what you want in your html element.  Should you be calling another method of the wf object instead?

Comment: I think this is the issue. the error also says so. And it works fine with the string values. But is there a way i can pass that object on click of button because i want to display the details of that object in another partial.

Comment: You need to think about what's happening here:  the user clicks on something, that generates another request to your server, the server generates some html, and then you either show the whole page (redirect) or replace part of the page (ajax).  So, if you're communicating with the server,you do that with *parameters*.  Sending the id of an object is the most efficient way to tell the server which object you want it to use to make the partial.